# Flutter Change Body Widget When Data Is Loaded

Tags: flutter, progress-bar

Im new to Flutter and with my app I want to show ProgressBar indicator widget when fetching data from backend and when data is fetched show another information widget, I just don't Know how to do that?

I tried below code and its just work fine! but I don't know if this is the prober way to do it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class UserLocation extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _UserLocationState createState() => _UserLocationState();
}



class _UserLocationState extends State<UserLocation> {

  bool isLoading;

  @override
    void initState() {
      isLoading = true;
      getData();
      super.initState();
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return makeBody(

    );
  }


  Widget indicator(){
    return Scaffold(

        backgroundColor: Colors.red,

    );
  }

  Widget showData(){
    return Scaffold(

        backgroundColor: Colors.green,

    );
  }

  Widget makeBody(){
      if(isLoading){
        return this.indicator();
      }else{
        return this.showData();
      }
  }

  Future getData() async{

      var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull('http://xxxx'));
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
            isLoading = false;
            setState(() {
              var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
              var data = jsonResponse['data'] as List;
             print(data);
            });


      }else{
        isLoading = false;
        print("Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.");
      }

    }
}
```

Any help , ideas will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are getting a response code other than 200 from the API, and you are not using setState when the response is other than 200

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class UserLocation extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _UserLocationState createState() => _UserLocationState();
}



class _UserLocationState extends State<UserLocation> {

  bool isLoading;

  @override
    void initState() {
      isLoading = true;
      getData();
      super.initState();
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return makeBody(

    );
  }


  Widget indicator(){
    return Scaffold(

        backgroundColor: Colors.red,

    );
  }

  Widget showData(){
    return Scaffold(

        backgroundColor: Colors.green,

    );
  }

  Widget makeBody(){
      if(isLoading){
        return this.indicator();
      }else{
        return this.showData();
      }
  }

  Future getData() async{

      var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull('http://xxxx'));
      if(response.statusCode == 200){

            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
              var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
              var data = jsonResponse['data'] as List;
             print(data);
            });


      }else{
        setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
         });


        print("Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.");
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i just want to ask if the concept is correct